# Is "anti" used in Latin?

Tags: greek, prefix

Apparently, [anti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anti-) is a word already available in [Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%AF#Ancient_Greek), meaning against. However, it seems this word [did not reach Latin](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=anti&lang=la).

Still, Wikipedia entries of common English words that have anti as prefix are incorporated into Latin, keeping the anti prefix. For example, [anticapitalismus](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticapitalismus), [antivirus](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus), [antiglobalisation](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motus_antiglobalisticus), etc.

I imagine these words adapt the English word that does exist in Latin (e.g. capitalism to capitalismum), but keep the *anti* prefix for simplicity, or maybe because there is no such prefix in Latin. **Is there?**

In other words, if you were to translate anticapitalism literally, how would you say it? Something like *in capitalismi* or *adversus capitalismi*? For example,

> Modus in capitalismi est in cresente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest Latin prefix I can think of is *contra-*.
I'm not sure if it as exact synonym of *anti-*, but certainly close enough for many purposes; both *contra-* and *anti-* mean "against".
The English prefix "counter-" appears to be a descendant of this Latin prefix.

It seems that in front of words related to *vertere*, it is often *contro-* instead of *contra-*.

The prefix is attested, but appears to be post-classical.
Perhaps it was more purely a preposition in the classical period, and merged with some other words later on.
I found these examples in L&S:

- [*contradicere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontradico)
- [*contradictio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontradictio)
- [*contradictor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontradictor)
- [*contrafactio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontrafactio)
- [*contraiuris*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontrajuris)
- [*contraponere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontrapono)
- [*contrascriba*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontrascriba)
- [*contrascribere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontrascribo)
- [*contrascriptor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontrascriptor)
- [*contravenire*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontravenio)
- [*contraversum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontraversum)
- [*contraversus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontraversus)
- [*controversia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontroversia)
- [*controversari*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontroversor)
- [*controversus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcontroversus)

I think the prefix can be used productively in a modern context.
I believe *contracapitalismus* is quite understandable.
However, for established technical terms, I would prefer to keep the original prefix *anti-*.
Greek influences are not a particularly non-Latin phenomenon.

Concerning your example of anticapitalism, there is a difference in English between "anticapitalism" and "against capitalism".
Semantically they are close, but their syntactic behavior is different.
If you want to translate the concept anticapitalism in Latin, I would go with *anticapitalismus*, but I would also consider *contracapitalismus*, depending on context.

Answer (score 6):

Classical Latin does of course have anti- in Greek loanwords (e.g. antithesis), but does not seem to use it in combination with Latin words.